# How to check for user authentication in Django's class-based view with get_context_data

Tags: python, django

When using function based views in Django, I normally would check for user authentication with:

```py
if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/path/to/redirect')
```

Now I am trying to use Class based views instead but I don't know how to implement the authentication if I am using the `get_context_data()` method instead of just `get()`.

```py
class MyGenericView(generic.ListView):
    model = models.MyModel
    template_name = 'path/to/template.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['foo'] = 'bar'

        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to override the *dispatch* method.

```
class MyView(ListView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/path/to/redirect')

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

More details [in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) in the view to check if the user is authenitcated:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin , ListView):
    login_url = “login_url_name”
    # rest of the code
```

You can also use [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test), for example, in urls:

```
def user_authenticated(user):
    return user.is_authenticated


urlpatterns = [
    path(
       '',
        user_passes_test(user_authenticated, login_url='login')(
            MyView.as_view()
        ),
    )
]
```

Comment: How can I set a `HttpResponseRedirect` with `LoginRequireMixin`?

Comment: You need to add a attribute named login_url. It will automatically redirect there if validation fails.I have updated my answer. BTW, you do not need that if you have defined ’LOGIN_URL’ in settings.py